# C# Dynamic Test for fields before aggregation functions like GroupBy

Tags: c#, dynamic

Assume the following code:

```
        var citizens = await _stateProvider.SelectWhere(whereParams);
        var retDto = new PercentGroupBy()
        {
            Total = citizens.Count,
            Elements = citizens.GroupBy(p => p.Content.Current.AggState.ToString()).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
        };
        return retDto;
```

citizens is a list of the following class:

```
public class Citizen    {
    public string ETag { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public dynamic Content { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best option to test that "p.Content.Current.AggState" property exists?

SelectWhere might return a few citizens where Content.Current is null and therefore asking for AggState throws error.

Answer (score 0):

Oops I found the answer while posting the question, so here it is to share the knowledge:

Add a fluid "Where" before "GroupBy"

```
    var citizens = await _stateProvider.SelectWhere(whereParams);
    var retDto = new PercentGroupBy()
    {
        Total = citizens.Count,
        Elements = citizens
        .Where(p => p.Content.Current != null)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Content.Current.AggState.ToString())
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
    };
    return retDto;
```